In Webgl how to check a texture whether it is filled with empty pixels (0, 0, 0, 0)?
A texture might be massive like over size of 4k*5k. I think readPixels and check by CPU might be slow.
I need a tricky method to improve the performance about the progress of checking for a 'null' texture. Features in Webgl2 are available.

In general yuo need to avoid big image data. One case is to optimise max size of img file.
In other way no need "tricky method".
Usually engines there a always default texture in case of "img data not ready at the first draw calls".
For example on onload image i push texture to the object.textures in that
case there is no warning and error logs.
Handling streaming/cubemap/simple textures
Draw procedure from my project texture part:
  // T
  if(object.vertexTexCoordBuffer) {
    world.GL.gl.bindBuffer(world.GL.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, object.vertexTexCoordBuffer);

    if(object.geometry.dynamicBuffer == true) {
      world.GL.gl.bufferData(world.GL.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, object.geometry.texCoords, world.GL.gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    world.GL.gl.vertexAttribPointer(object.shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute, object.vertexTexCoordBuffer.itemSize, world.GL.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    world.GL.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(object.shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute);

    if(object.streamTextures != null) {
      // video/webcam tex
      // App.tools.loadVideoTexture('glVideoTexture', object.streamTextures.videoImage);
      if(object.streamTextures.video) {
        App.tools.loadVideoTexture('glVideoTexture', object.streamTextures.video);
      } else {
        App.tools.loadVideoTexture('glVideoTexture', object.streamTextures.videoImage);
      }
      world.GL.gl.uniform1i(object.shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);

    } else if(object.FBO) {
      // test FBO
      // spot light test light
      // Fbo staff
      world.GL.gl.activeTexture(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE0);
      world.GL.gl.bindTexture(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, object.FBO.FB.texture);
      world.GL.gl.uniform1i(object.shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);

    } else {
      for(var t = 0;t < object.textures.length;t++) {
        if(object.custom.gl_texture == null) {
          world.GL.gl.activeTexture(world.GL.gl['TEXTURE' + t]);
          world.GL.gl.bindTexture(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, object.textures[t]);
          world.GL.gl.pixelStorei(world.GL.gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, false);
          if(object.texParams.MIPMAP == false) {
            world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, object.texParams.TEXTURE_WRAP_S | world.GL.gl.REPEAT);
            world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, object.texParams.TEXTURE_WRAP_T | world.GL.gl.REPEAT);
            // -- Allocate storage for the texture
            // world.GL.gl.texStorage2D(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 1, world.GL.gl.RGB8, 512, 512);
            // world.GL.gl.texSubImage2D(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0,512, 512, world.GL.gl.RGB, world.GL.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, object.textures[t]);
          } else {
            world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, object.texParams.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER | world.GL.gl.LINEAR);
            world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, object.texParams.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER | world.GL.gl.LINEAR);
            world.GL.gl.generateMipmap(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D);
          }

          if(world.GL.extTFAnisotropic && object.texParams.ANISOTROPIC == true) {
            world.GL.gl.texParameterf(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D,
              world.GL.extTFAnisotropic.TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT,
              world.GL.MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT);
          }

          //console.log('TEST' , object.texParams)
          world.GL.gl.uniform1i(object.shaderProgram.samplerUniform, t);

        } else {
          object.custom.gl_texture(object, t);
        }
      }
    }
    localLooper = localLooper + 1;
  } else {

    if(object.shaderProgram.samplerUniform) {
      world.GL.gl.uniform1i(object.shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);
    } else if(object.shaderProgram.uCubeMapSampler) {
      // CUBE MAP
      world.GL.gl.activeTexture(world.GL.gl['TEXTURE0']);
      var gl = world.GL.gl;
      if(!object.tex) object.tex = gl.createTexture();
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, object.tex);
      if(object.cubeMap.type == 'images') {
        object.cubeMap.cubeMap2dCanvasSet.forEach((faceInfo, index) => {
          const level = 0;
          const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
          const format = gl.RGBA;
          const type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
          gl.texImage2D(faceInfo.target, level, internalFormat, format, type, object.cubeMap.images[index]);
          gl.pixelStorei(world.GL.gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, false);
        });
      } else {
        object.cubeMap.cubeMap2dCanvasSet.forEach((faceInfo, index) => {
          var args = [];
          for(var key in faceInfo) {
            if(key !== 'target') {
              args.push(faceInfo[key]);
            }
          }
          if(object.cubeMap.drawFunc) {
            object.cubeMap.drawFunc(args);
          } else {
            const {faceColor, textColor, text} = faceInfo;
            gen2DTextFace(object.cubeMap.cubeMap2dCtx, faceColor, textColor, text);
          }
          const level = 0;
          const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
          const format = gl.RGBA;
          const type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
          gl.texImage2D(faceInfo.target, level, internalFormat, format, type, object.cubeMap.cubeMap2dCtx.canvas);
          gl.pixelStorei(world.GL.gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, false);
        });
      }
      gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
      world.GL.gl.uniform1i(object.shaderProgram.uCubeMapSampler, 0);
    }
  }

  world.GL.gl.bindBuffer(world.GL.gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, object.vertexIndexBuffer);
  world.setMatrixUniforms(object, this.pMatrix, object.mvMatrix);


Thanks for your patience. Actually I just coding about a paint selection part. With alt key, if all of the selection is blended as deleted, I need special note for it, so the texture is always ready.
